# What cookies can a js script loaded from an external domain access?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Assume a web app (served over http) has a  tag with a src that is another domain. The external script is doing things with cookies and/or localStorage. What domains cookies can it access?

`<!-- on example.org -->
<script src='http://anotherexample.org/script.js'> <!-- This script messes with cookies -->`

My intuition tells me the the cookies that it manipulates are those that belong to example.org. But how does this work?

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition is pretty much correct. Cookies were created before browsers began to implement same origin policy restrictions and, thus, are [not generally protected](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_cookies) by those policies. So when the script delivered by `anotherexample.org` accesses `document.cookie` it will see those cookies delivered by `example.org` in the original HTTP response.

The only significant exception is for ["HttpOnly" cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Overview). If `example.org` chooses, it can designate cookies that it delivers as "HttpOnly"; those cookies cannot be accessed by any JavaScript code, whether from `anotherexample.org` or even `example.org` itself.